# how do i fix "No module named 'win32api'" on python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32

I am trying to import win32api in python 2.7.9. i did the "pip install pypiwin32" and made sure all the files were intalled correctly (i have the win32api.pyd under ${PYTHON_HOME}\Lib\site-packages\win32). i also tried coping the files from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32 to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32. I also tried restarting my pc after each of these steps but nothing seems to work! i still get the error 'No module named 'win32api''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out the answer is upgrading my python to 3.6.
python 2.7 seems to old to work with outside imports (I'm just guessing here, because its not the first time I'm having an import problem)
hope it helps :)